# Using one Data frame cell value to retrieve information from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, vectorization

I have two Dataframes. One contains prices of stocks listed on NSE with stock code as column name and date as the index. Another table of universe of 500 stocks that can be traded(There is different stock every day). I am trying to create a third Dataframe which will fetch the data from on first DF and map it to 500 stock.

````
```
test_portfolio=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Stock"+str(x+1) for x in range(531)],index=df2.index)
num_col=len(df2.columns)
num_row=len(df2)
for r in range(num_row):
    for c in range(num_col):
        test_portfolio.iat[r,c]=final[df2.iloc[r][c]][r]
return test_portfolio
````

This loop is taking too much of time. Is there any way to vectorize it or reduce time taken?

[image: DF snapshot]

Comment: Do you have to assign? Can't you just filter the first dataframe using `isin`?

Comment: Can you  please add some sample input and the expected output

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu Every cell in df2 is different on every day ...I am just doing lookup in final DF and placing corresponding value in test_portfolio

Comment: @heretolearn I have enclosed the DF snapshot...let me know if you require anything else

Comment: can you just print the head of final and df2. This is really easy to solve with `isin`

Comment: already enclosed DF snapshot for both..I wants to replace stock code in each cell in DF2 with prices and save it as new dataframe...

Comment: @MukulMehta Can you add it as a text instead of image. It is difficult to replicate the dataframe from image

Answer (score 0):

I think using merge will be more suitable. Take a look at:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html